# Change URL paths of sharepoint folders

Tags: 2010

We have what I think is a unique situation in our sharepoint deployment. Our network admins want to redirect only certain url requests to our application from the loadbalancer. For example https://yoursite.com/SPsite would hit our application and any other url would hit some other application (non sharepoint).

The problem is that some of the urls that sharepoint generates like (_layouts, webresource.axd etc.) are still at the root level and it is causing problems on outbound links. For example, sharepoint generates a script link at _layout/init.js and it will fail at the load balancer level.

We can use urlrewrite but then we are having problems with PPS.

IS there an elegant solution to this problem? IDeally if I can get sharepoint to generate links like SPSite/_layouts, that would solve my problem. I am hoping that there is some hidden setting which can help me configure it the way I want.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Never use URL rewrite, you will have problems down the line with bad references. I guess the first step is asking yourself why the network admins want to redirect only certain url requests to another application? SharePoint and URL rewriting do not work well with each other in the long run. You can set up explicit managed paths in the web application in Central Administration if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: We have kinda figured out that urlrewrite or using a reverse proxy does not work well with sharepoint. 
Using explicit managed paths does work for the pages and controls but sharepoint generates some scripts and links that still refer to the root path. 
Our company is cheap ass and wants to share a single url with multiple applications.. We do not have any control over that unfortunately

Comment: SharePoint has recommendations just like any program, platform, OS, etc. These are set in place to ensure consistent usability. If you don't abide by them, it's more of a "use at your own risk".